# What are App Domains in Facebook Apps?

Tags: facebook

I want to add the ability to 'login with Facebook' to my site. But I am confused when I register my site in Facebook Apps. What should I input into `App Domains`?

Comment: I think it's just the domain of your site (e.g. example.com)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

the app domain is your domain name.

Before you enter your domain, first click on Add Platform, select website, enter your site URL and mobile site url. Save the settings.

Thereafter, you can enter the domain name in the App domains field.

See more at my blog: http://www.ogbongeblog.com/2014/03/unable-to-add-app-domains-to-new.html

Comment: What if I develop an iOS or Android app instead of a website? What domain should I put in that case? My API domain or what?

Comment: I can add "App domains" field like example.com/name ?

Comment: url 404 page not found

Answer (score 28):

If you don't specify the ***platform*** for the app you won't able to add app domain correctly.

Here is an example -- validate that its a type a website platform. 
[image]

Answer (score 25):

To add to the answers above, the App Domain is required for security reasons. For example, your app has been sending the browser to `"www.example.com/PAGE_NAME_HERE"`, but suddenly a third party application (or something else) sends the user to `"www.supposedlymaliciouswebsite.com/PAGE_HERE"`, then a 191 error is thrown saying that this wasn't part of the app domains you listed in your Facebook application settings.

Comment: @KyleGobel Well, in the title he ask what "app domain" is, right?

Comment: What if I create a virtual host on my local machine and then set it to the exact `www.example.com` host. Will Facebook block it?

Answer (score 9):

In this example:

http://**www.example.com:80**/somepage?parameter1="hello"&parameter2="world"

the bold part is the Domainname. 80 is rarely included. I post it since many people may wonder if 3000 or some other port is part of the domain if their not staging their app for production yet. Normally you don't specify it since 80 is the default, but if you just want to specify `localhost` just do it without the port number, it works just as fine. The adress, though, should be `http://localhost:3000` (if you have it on that port).

Answer (score 4):

it stands for your website where your app is running on.
like you have made an app www.xyz.pqr
then you will type this www.xyz.pqr in App domain
the site where your app is running on should be secure and valid

Answer (score 1):

It's simply the domain that your "facebook" application (wich means application visible on facebook but hosted on the website www.xyz.com) will be hosted. So you can put App Domain = www.xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the domain that you run your app.

For example, your canvas URL is facebook.yourdomain.com, you should give App domain as .yourdomain.com

Comment: my url is http://ec2-46-51-248-9.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9090/static/index.php...can you tell me what would i put in app domain

Comment: You should put the whole thing but not the stuff after .com in the app domain: ec2-46-51-248-9.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

In case you developing an iOS or Android app instead of a website, just remove value from `app domains` field.