# What is App Domain in Facebook Apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

What is App Domain used for in Facebook Apps?

Somebody had asked the same in [What are App Domains in Facebook Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574344/what-is-app-domain-in-facebook-apps) but I didn't really get it.

What I am trying to do is "publish actions" from a mobile app.  The object to be published must be stored in a separate web page.  And the domain of the separate page is supposed to be included in app domains.

Is app domain applicable for Mobile apps as well?

Answer (score 2):

Well AppDomain simply means where is located your application's server side files.
Your application only usable from that domain. Facebook needs data for cross domain and security issues.

Unless you're going to use FB auth for a website you don't need to fill App Domain input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I mentioned earlier, I have a mobile game, which needs to publish actions on facebook (For Eg. So-and-so has drawn a <PICTURE> on <MY GAME>)  The <PICTURE> object needs to be stored in an external web page.  Facebook requires that I add the domain of the external web page to my app domains field.  So will that give me any problems if I add the external domain to my add domains?

Comment: @SatheeshJM i may not get exactly what you mean, but it doesn't matter where you store image files. Most of the applications already uses file storage services. like amazon etc.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue for my mobile app. To fix it, I set the App Domain to my domain. But that wasn't enough because I then got the error:

> Error
>   You have specified an App Domains but have not specified a Site URL or a Mobile Web URL
>   puurbuy.com must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL.

So  I had to go one step further and enable "Website with Facebook Login" setting the URL to my homepage, even though I do not have a Facebook login on my website. A terrible work around in my opinion, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Because not using Sandbox Mode:
1. Had to establish a category on appdetails page
2. Had to set Website with Facebook Login
3. Then able to set App Domain

Now the debug pulls in the correct information without error.

Answer (score 0):

App domain is not something related to your app or web domain, this is basically a App Store address.
Simply write this line in App Domains.

```
apps.apple.com
```

this worked for me.