# Facebook app: how do I add Mobile Site URL?

Tags: c#, facebook, azure-mobile-services

I have an app that has separate back ends for the mobile app and the web portal; I would like to use the same Facebook app to manage both.

My app address is (with domain names changed)

https://myapp.online

and the mobile app lives at

https://myapp.azurewebsites.net

When I try to add both of these domains to the "app domains" section in my Facebook app, I get the message

> App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL
>   (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab
>   URL. Please correct these domains: myapp.azurewebsites.net"

Notice that "Mobile Site URL" and "Site URL" are listed as separate options, leading me to suspect that it should be possible to add a Mobile Site URL separately from the Site URL, which I've included by adding a website from the "Add Platform" menu. But I can't find any way of adding the Mobile Site URL in the Facebook Developer Console.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Mobile Site URL is part of the Games platform (formerly know as Canvas) settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom domain for myapp.azurewebsites.net which points to mobile.myapp.online and the add mobile.myapp.online as mobile URL in FB.

Then FB will not complain...

Answer (score 2):

As CBroe mentioned, **Mobile Site URL** belongs to **Facebook Web Games** platform as follows:

[image]

Also, I found a legacy issue about [App Domains in Facebook Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574344/what-are-app-domains-in-facebook-apps) mentioned that choose Website platform then you could enter **Site URL** and **Mobile Site URL** as follows:

[image]

Based on your requirement, I assumed that you could leverage virtual directory to deploy your two projects to a single azure web app. For more details, you could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/). Then you could access them as follows:

**Web Portal**: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net

**Mobile back-end**：https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/services

Also, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name) about mapping your custom domain to azure website.