# Facebook API site URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

My website's user management is totally done via facebook login. And I've specified the site URL as `sitename.com` inside the Facebook app. However, when the site is visited with `www` infront as `www.sitename.com`, the facebook API fails to work. But if I change the site URL inside the Facebook app to `www.sitename.com`, it works perfectly. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Before we can suggest anything to fix the issue, we would first of all need to know what “fails to work” _actually_ means.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. Redirect all the traffics from `www` to `non-www` in .htaccess
2. Add the `www` domain to `App Domains`, in facebook app settings.

See more: [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess), [What are App Domains in Facebook Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574344/what-are-app-domains-in-facebook-apps)