B2C authentication with existing Facebok account fails with "Invalid consumer domain for social signup" error
I properly configured my external tenant with social B2C external identity providers: Google and Facebook.
When testing Signup and sign in user flow I am able to login with my Google account which creates a user in my tenant with Identity: google.com
I am trying to do the same with my facebook account for which I use my personal email: let's say rad@mydomain.com
I can reach login screen from Facebook ant it noticed I was already signed in with my personal domain  and want me to continue as me: Rad,
but when I press Continue I get error:
Invalid consumer domain for social signup
When I try to log in with my email rad@mydomain.com on the Azure portal, I am getting error:
Selected user account does not exist in tenant
‘Microsoft Services' and cannot access the
application 'aced0c89 b2f1-27b67d3f0054" in that tenant.
So I was thinking to login to my Azure account with my personal rad@mydomain.com (I think was able to do that before and to just have free services. I didn't do anything special like creating a new AD tenant - I am even not sure if that is possible with a free account)
So now I cannot use my Facebook integration with my personal email.
I want to build a SaaS application with B2C and social integration and I want to avoid this situation with some users being in the similar situation of not being able to use some of their social account.




Check twice how you configured your Facebook App (App Domain) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574344/what-are-app-domains-in-facebook-apps

The issue is that I don’t have a valid, active domain yet. I registered a domain, but I don’t have a live website to link to, so there’s nothing actually set up. I believe the problem stems from the type of information I’m requesting from my B2C authentication setup. I’m asking for all available details, like email, display name, and other fields that require business verification. The challenge is that I’m not a business; I’m just an individual without a business entity. This seems to have put me in a loop where I can’t proceed.
Can I avoid business verification

This could be because you have incorrectly configured the B2C domain in Facebook.
In "Valid OAuth redirect URIs", check that you correctly entered:
https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

I have a Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription – MPN in a company I am working for. I created mytool external tenant with Google and Facebook. Redirect URI in my case (which worked for google) is https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/fee18a92-2ade-...c39ab74/oauth2/authresp
I can confirm when redirecting 302 to facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=463545623404790&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%2ffee18a92-2ade-...39ab74%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=code The message says my email is used in some enerprise domain. I want to fix it somehow!!!
